# Missing base SDK in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, sdk

I am using Xcode 6 and in the lefthand pane under the project name it is telling me:

'0 targets, missing base SDK'.

I have tried finding a solution to this problem online and there does not seem to be one.

I am using a macbook pro version 10.9.5

Answer (score 4):

File->New->Target->Choose a template->fill out all the information->Finish

That should do it, you'll need to manually create a target.